# How to set Local Timezone when saving time into DB in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, timezone, time

I have applied following things to make Default time zone to my local timezone i.e. **'Asia/Calcutta'** --

1) changed in **config.xml -**

```
<general>
            <locale>
                <code>en_US</code>
                <timezone>Asia/Calcutta</timezone>
            </locale>
 </general>
```

2) Changed in **Mage.php -**

```
 if (is_readable($localConfigFile)) {
                $localConfig = simplexml_load_file($localConfigFile);
                date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
                if (($date = $localConfig->global->install->date) && strtotime($date)) {
                    self::$_isInstalled = true;
                }
  }
```

Now when I am trying to insert any time in db using this code

`Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`,

it does not work according to current timezone and saves 5:30 hours ahead date in DB. can anyone tell me how can I do it or Have I done something wrong in default timezone settings.

Comment: Why would you do that? Just set the time on your server.

Comment: I have done that already before doing all above.

Comment: Why would you want that? As long as it is converted correct when the data is shown in the backend I think it's fine?

Comment: Then How can I save date in Db in my timezone and other plugins are also using above code to save date in DB.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need to do it go to **System > Configuration > General > General > Localization options** and change the default timezone to "India Standard Time" then Save.
I think this is what prevents you from having the right time saved in the DB.

Comment: I have already done that.

Comment: ok, create a test.php as the root of your Magento, then load Magento in it and `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`, tell us what it outputs.

Comment: Yes it shows correct time...But I have to change this code at many place even in other plugins as well which is not good.

Comment: I don't see why you bothered with `Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` in the first place, because PHP's `date()` will scale with the server's time. I'm sorry but I don't have an answer for your problem then.